# Configuring connection pool size with guice, mybatis, and c3p0 or bonecp

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, guice, c3p0, bonecp

I'm using Guice/Mybatis to manage and execute my queries to a MySQL database.  My class that sets up the connection and extends MyBatisModule contains these relevant bits:

```
Properties myBatisProperties = new Properties();
myBatisProperties.setProperty("c3p0.maxPoolSize", "5");
myBatisProperties.setProperty("c3p0.initialPoolSize", "5");
bindDataSourceProviderType(C3p0DataSourceProvider.class);
bindTransactionFactoryType(JdbcTransactionFactory.class);
addMapperClass(getMapperClass());
Names.bindProperties(binder(), myBatisProperties);
bind(getBindServiceClass()).to(getBindServiceToClass());
```

When I configure either using c3p0 or bonecp using its properties of `bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition` and `bonecp.partitionCount`, and the appropriate `DataSourceProvider.class` in place of `C3p0DataSourceProvider`, both c3p0 and bonecp ignore my max connections configuration and just open (and hold open) a new connection for every query until mysql runs out of available connections.

When I use the default mybatis pool provider `PooledDataSourceProvider` and its properties, `mybatis.pooled.maximumActiveConnections` and `mybatis.pooled.maximumIdleConnections`, it respects my configuration and pools connections correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Further documentation for this is available at http://mybatis.github.io/guice/datasources.html

Comment: re c3p0: c3p0 dumps its configuration at INFO upon pool initialization. check your logs and verify that the settings you desire have made it to the DataSource. if not, there are lots of other ways to get c3p0 configured than via the wrapper you are using.

Comment: Strange...  3cp0 claims its max pool size is 5: `[ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> true, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 5, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0]`

Comment: (I removed several things from that to fit the comment size limit.  If there's something you don't see there that might be relevant let me know and I'll post it)

Comment: AHA!  Here's the problem.  The C3P0 pool gets initialized more than once during the application's lifetime.  It's once once per query, but it's happening once every couple queries.  I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was due to the my creating a new injector every time.  Specifically this line:

`Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyDAOPoolModule());
return injector.getInstance(MyDAOService.class);`

If instead I make the injector a singleton, it only creates the one pool.